# filter rows where a column has a string 'car' but not 'carry'

Tags: r, string

How can I filter rows based on column values that have "car" but don't contain "carry" using grep or any other library?

```
rows <- (df[grep("car", df$item_text),])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you do want for example 'car1' and 'car2', but not 'carry':

```
rows <- df[grepl("car", df$item_text) & !grepl("carry", df$item_text),]
```

Example data:

```
df = data.frame(item_text=c("car1","car2","carry","carry1"),id=seq(1,4))
```

Example output:

```
  item_text id
1      car1  1
2      car2  2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rows <- df[df$item_text=="car",]
```

Comment: If the word `car` is within a string (which I assume to be the case based on OP's `grep` request) then your method will not work

Answer (score 0):

```
df = data.frame(item_text = c("car", "a car", "my carry", "carry a car", "something"))    
subset(df, subset = grepl("car", df$item_text) & !grepl("carry", df$item_text))
```

Comment: @akrun I m not the downvoter but maybe because the same answer was posted earlier by another user

Comment: @Sotos But, if you check that answer, it is not right, `grep` gives a numeric index.  so the logical  `&` won't work

Comment: @akrun I am not following. Both answers use `grepl`

Comment: The other answer using grep is now edited to grepl and works correctly. I still don't really understand the downvote.

Comment: I didn't refresh the page,  so probably it get refreshed.  I was commenting based on this

`Assuming you do want for example 'car1' and 'car2', but not 'carry':

rows <- df[grep("car", df$item_text) & !grep("carry", df$item_text),]`

Comment: Oh. There is no edit history there so can't tell which came first.

Comment: @akrun I missed that and there is no edit history (I wonder why)

Comment: At least from my screen, Ape's one is `grepl` and other is `grep`

Comment: I believe you, I m just saying that there is not an edit button to see the history

Comment: Akrun is right, I modified my answer a few seconds after posting, because I realized OP used grep instead of grepl. I think Ape and I stumbled upon the same solution. Strange though that there is no edit history of my post?